# error when non Super Admin tries to create new member with front end registration form

Tags: solspace-user

We would like to have one non SuperAdmin member group be able to add new members using the User registration form. While it’s not completely clear, it appears from the documentation that this is doable by giving permissions to the member group, and including admin_register=“yes” as a parameter in the form. I am using EE 3.4.5 and User 4.0.8.

The form is allowing SuperAdmin to create the new members, but not the alternate member group that has the permissions to Create, Edit and Delete members. Instead, when the form is submitted, I get the following message:
'The form you submitted contained the following errors
You are already registered and logged in.'

I am able to view the form, but it won't submit due to the error.

The documentation states:
admin_register="yes"
This parameter allows users of member groups that are allowed to administrate members to view the Register form, and submit new user registrations on behalf of others. Using this parameter will prevent the auto-login feature after registration from working (so the admin doesn't become logged in as the member they just created).

The following is my registration form, and I am testing it logged in as the non Super Admin member group that has the added member permissions to Create, Edit and Delete members:

```
{exp:user:register admin_register="yes" group_id="5" return="/membership/add-new-members/success" error_page="/membership/error"}
   <p>
    <label for="first_name" class="form-label" >First Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" required value="{if first_name}{first_name}{/if}"/>
 </p>
  <p>
    <label for="last_name" class="form-label">Last Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control" required value="{if last_name}{last_name}{/if}"/>
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="username" name="username" id="username" placeholder="name@domain.com" class="form-control">
  </p>
   <p>
      <label for="password" class="form-label form-label">Password  <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" value="{if password}{password}{/if}"/>
   </p>
  <p>
    <label for="password" class="form-label form-label">Confirm Password  <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="password" name="password_confirm" id="password_confirm" class="form-control" value="{if password_confirm}{password_confirm}{/if}"/>
<p>
    {if captcha}
    <p>
        <label for="captcha">{lang:captcha}*</label>
        {captcha}<br/>
        <input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" style="width:140px;"/>
    </p>
    {/if}

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create Account" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</p>
{/exp:user:register}
```

Am I missing a step?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Solspace User throws this error because of the following:

```
1) admin_register is not set to yes.
2) Member Group is not Super admin & can_admin_members is not set to 'y'.
```

So,It might be a possible solspace user bug because `can_admin_members` field is available in the `EE2` but was replaced by `can_create_members`,`can_edit_members`,`can_delete_members` in `EE3`.

Comment: Thank you Jainil. I'll contact Solspace about possible bug.